# Passing an array to a named port connection

Tags: verilog

If I am sending some parameters to any module in verilog like:

```
SUM( .a(a), .b(b), .out(out));
```

It will work fine. What if I want to pass an array as input or want to take arrays as output? For example:

```
integer  a=10;
  integer  b=20;
  integer  c[2:0]={2,4,6};
  integer  d=0;

any module(.input1(a), .input2(b), .input3(c),.....)
```

But it will give error that "cannot access memory c directly".

So, how can I send or receive an array in named port connection?

Comment: Show the declarations of `a`, `b` and `c`. And the module. A minimal but FULL example code will be good.

Comment: To be clear when you say 'sending some parameters' your actually talking about connecting inputs. Parameters are constants in verilog, and input ports are describing physical connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs can be arrays from SystemVerilog 2009. Verilog 1995, 2001 and 2005 do not support array ports.

```
module dut(
  input [7:0] a [3:0]
);

endmodule
```